# MongoDB slow find

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I got this collection created from mongoose:

```
var ethTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    blockNumber: Number,
    blockHash: String,
    hash: String,
    transactionIndex: Number,
    from: String,
    to: String,
    value: String
});
ethTransactionSchema.index({ hash: 1 }, { unique: true });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1});

ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: 1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ transactionIndex: 1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: -1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 });
```

If I execute this query:

```
find({$or: [from: '0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad', 
            to: '0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad'
           ]})
     .sort({blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1}).limit(20)
```

I get excellent performance:

```
It chooses these indexes (from explain())
{
        "from" : 1,
        "blockNumber" : 1,
        "transactionIndex" : 1
}
{
        "to" : 1,
        "blockNumber" : 1,
        "transactionIndex" : 1
}
```

But when executing this query:

```
find({$and: [{$or: [{from: '0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad'}, 
                    {to: '0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad'}
                   ]}, 
             {blockNumber: {$lte: 1700000}}
            ]}).sort({blockNumber:-1, transactionIndex: -1}).limit(21)
```

I get poor performance and sometimes it takes more than 20 seconds to return results (most times takes less than a second). It chooses these indexes:

```
{
       "from": 1
{
{
      "to": 1
}
```

If the time were predictable in less than a second it would be acceptable but the first query takes some times 20 or 30 seconds, which is completely unacceptable.
Executing the same queries from Mongo Shell I get the same results.

Can someone point me to a solution?

Thanks on advanced,
P/

Comment: Start by removing parts of your query, like the sorting, to see if that helps make MongoDB pick a better index. Also, it may be worthwhile to provide a [hint](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-hint) to point towards an index that might perform better.

Comment: The first query it the slowest, it looks like the hint could help but I see that explain chooses 2 indexes. Is it possible to choose these 2?

Comment: AFAIK, explain will show the indexes that MongoDB chooses to use, which may not necessarily be the best. Perhaps the `{ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }` index may work better for your query. First query being the slowest sounds like caches are being primed (and subsequently used for following queries).

Comment: if I try to adding hint({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }) it takes forever.

Comment: If I remove the sort the query is executed fast.

Comment: Yeah, I've had issues like this myself. I found it a bit of a trial-and-error process, and also reading up on how MongoDB uses indexes (sometimes the order in which you state your query or sort parameters makes a big difference, for instance).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117824/discussion-between-pablo-yabo-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
find().lean()
```

lean command gives results in plain object. It will increase performance.

Comment: The issue also occurs in the MongoDB shell, so it's related to the query itself, not to Mongoose.

Comment: As robertklep says the issue is about the query and is reproduced in the shell, but it was a good tip to add to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround of the issue. It was impossible to make the $or query work fine. I reduced the query to:

```
find({$and: [{from: '0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad'}, 
             {blockNumber: {$lte: 1700000}}
            ]}).sort({blockNumber:-1, transactionIndex: -1}).limit(21)
```

and:

```
find({$and: [{to: '0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad'}, 
             {blockNumber: {$lte: 1700000}}
            ]}).sort({blockNumber:-1, transactionIndex: -1}).limit(21)
```

Then I merge the results by myself. It work excellent now but I thought I was using a real database, may be it's my fault. This db is just to play, if you try complex queries it isn't good enough.